# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast

Tags: java, android

I'm following this [Android-Checkout](https://github.com/serso/android-checkout) for in-app purchases. Just getting a feel for how it works. I have a pretty good idea how it all works but I get this problem.

This is my Sku Activity class and I get an error which corresponds with in the CheckoutApplication class

```
final Billing billing = CheckoutApplication.get(this).getmBilling();
    mCheckout = Checkout.forActivity(this, billing); //Line with error
    mCheckout.start();


//Separate class 
//This is where the other error is

public static CheckoutApplication get(Activity activity)
{
    return (CheckoutApplication) activity.getAcitivty();
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing the error. Any help is welcome. Thanks

> at
>   com.purchases.inapppurchases.CheckoutApplication.get(CheckoutApplication.java:37)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.purchases.inapppurchases.SkuActivity.onCreate(SkuActivity.java:68)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
public static CheckoutApplication get(Activity activity)
{
    return (CheckoutApplication) activity.getAcitivty();
}
```

with

```
public static CheckoutApplication get(Activity activity)
{
    return (CheckoutApplication) activity.getApplication();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (CheckoutApplication) activity.getAcitivty();
```

You are returning an Activity instead of an Application, this can't be cast successfully. Try returning and casting the actual application instead:

```
return (CheckoutApplication) activity.getApplication();
```